# Is there a way to obtain the function name of current function?

Tags: function, debugging, emacs, elisp

```
(defun foo ()
    (send-to-debug-log "Error. Function terminated." (get-current-function-name)))
```

I currently do this:

```
(defun foo ()
    (send-to-debug-log "Error. Function terminated." 'foo)))
```

Hard coding the function name seems not to be a good practice.
Any suggestion to implement the `get-current-function-name` or `get-function-name-that-call-me`.

Comment: You can try and play with `backtrace-frame` but I think a better solution would be to have `(get-current-function-name)` replaced by the function's name during macro-expansion (i.e. at compile-time).  Not only it'd be more efficient but it would also handle cases like lambda functions used as callbacks (where the englobing function may not be present at all in the backtrace).  So I strongly suggest you `M-x report-emas-bug` and request this as a feature.

Comment: What @Stefan said. (But a typo: `report-emacs-bug`.)

Answer (score 5):

```
(defun foo ()
  (send-to-debug-log "Error. Function terminated." (nth 1 (backtrace-frame 2))))
```

Comment: It is not really better than hard code the function name. The function you provided returns `send-to-debug-log`. To get `foo`, it needs to change to be `(backtrace-frame 3)`. In other words, this function depends on other functions enclosing it and is not flexible.

Comment: You can write a function which goes back in the backtrace until it finds the proper name. I just wanted to show you what to use. I apply a similar technique in Tramp, see `tramp-debug-message`.

Comment: I get it. Instead putting it in `foo`, it should be put in `send-to-debug-log`. The backtrace steps should always be constant.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
(defconst my-defun-macros '(defun cl-defun defmacro cl-defmacro))

(defun my-add-defun-name (orig-fun name &rest args)
  (let* ((my-current-defun-name (if (consp name) (cadr name) name))
         (macroexpand-all-environment
          (cons (cons 'my-get-current-function-name
                      (lambda () my-current-defun-name))
                macroexpand-all-environment))
         (code (apply orig-fun name args)))
    (macroexpand-all code macroexpand-all-environment)))

(defmacro my-get-current-function-name ()
  "Return current defun's name.
Only works within the advised macros in `my-defun-macros'."
  (error "my-get-current-function-name used outside of a defun"))

(dolist (m my-defun-macros)
  (advice-add m :around #'my-add-defun-name))
```

Comment: After having hard time understanding this. I have two questions. Should `(code (apply orig-fun name args))` be changed to `(code (apply orig-fun my-current-defun-name args))`.

Comment: Adding advice to `defun` is also a new concept to me. Would it apply to `defun` from other packages and other compiled packages?

Comment: Regarding your first question, no, the `name` should be passed unmodified to the original macro.  As to the second, it affects all uses of `defun`, so it's very intrusive.

Comment: I feel something wrong at this point. Since the `advice-add` is done at runtime, the `my-add-defun-name` must also be done at runtime, so is the macro expansion. And this method also adds overhead to all unrelated `defun`. It loses advantage in terms of efficiency. ?

Comment: In terms of performance, I don't think you'll ever be able to notice the difference: it only affects macro-expansion, i.e. either time to compile the files, or time to load the uncompiled files.  After that, `defun` is basically never seen any more.

Comment: I apperciate this answer and this works as its purpose. However, I cannot choose this as the best answer. First, it is too intrusive. Second, if people choose to use this method to debug the own package, it will turn out there will be more than one `advice` around `defun`s. I think I will go mad if I find that there are 10 advice around my `defun`.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you ever find 10 advices on your defun (`advice-add` is idempotent, so these would have to be 10 different advices), but even in that case I would be very surprised if it could make a noticeable performance difference.  I'd be more worried about unexpected interferences between them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that seems to work pretty well:

```
(defun calling-function ()
  (let ((n 6) ;; nestings in this function + 1 to get out of it
        func
        bt)
    (while (and (setq bt (backtrace-frame n))
              (not func))
        (setq n (1+ n)
              func (and bt
                      (nth 0 bt)
                      (nth 1 bt))))
    func))
```

If you call it in a lambda, you get the whole lambda.  It works with `apply`, `funcall`, and `eval`.

I think the most simple, robust way is to just explicitly write the function name, as you're doing now.

Comment: The shape of the backtrace is different if you byte-compile the code, so getting it to work "reliably" can be rather tricky.

Comment: @Stefan is right. It returns the correct function name when it has not been compiled. After compiled, it returned `call-interactively`.

Answer (score 1):

With the package `which-function-mode` (in melpa), you can programmatically call the function

```
(Which-function)
```

more info:

- https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/which-function-mode
- http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/04/05/which-function-mode/

Comment: It did not work after complie. The `which-function` use `with-current-buffer` to find the function defintion.