# Emacs lisp - can a defun reference itself somehow?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm wondering if code inside a defun can reference itself, with some sort of "'self" reference as is used in many other languages. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do (the code does not work):

```
(defun self-reference ()
  "Show function doc when the function is run."
  (message "%s" (documentation 'self)))
```

Is this kind of thing even possible? I couldn't find anything on the net, or in the Info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35907038/245173

Comment: Sorry to disagree, but I don't think my question is anywhere close to being a duplicate. I'm asking if there is a elisp language capability of self referencing, and the other question talks about various ways of inspecting backtraces (!!), or wrapping the original defun in macro calls. I already know how to wrap functions in macros. They are not the same thing at all.  (Besides, the search keywords for that question are quite different than the ones I used to search for 'self' 'reference', etc.) Nonetheless, I get the sense that the answer to my question is "No."

Comment: The answer to your question is "no". I believe if `defun` were written differently, it could transform `self` into `'self-reference`. But it's not.

Elisp doesn't have a built-in concept of `this` like in object-oriented languages, mainly because there aren't "objects" in Elisp. The closest thing to an object in Elisp is an assoc list, but that's more like a dictionary with entries rather than an object with fields. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Kevin: yes your question is a duplicate.  E.g. using my macro-based solution to the other question, you would just have to replace replace `self` with `(my-get-current-function-name)` in your code.

Comment: @BrianMalehorn emacs has oo feature called eieio.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at eieio, and CLOS quite a bit. All I wondered was if there was an elisp built-in way of referencing the defun name (even if a defun is not an object in the usual sense). I can see with all the traffic here that it might have been possible to ask it in a different way without triggering duplicates, etc. But I guess the good news is that the community is trying to help, and that much is obvious. Thanks to everyone.